# How to mount nfs with utf8 support on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, unicode, nfs, utf-8

In short, I have two ubuntu 16.04 servers. Both of them are using `en_US.utf-8`. Now I follow this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-16-04) to mount a nfs from one server to another. I have done it successfully, but there is a problem remain. Some files have a file name with utf-8 characters, they cannot be transformed correctly. For example, if I copy a file named `雷侯.txt` from client to server, it will become `??.txt`.

So how could I make it work?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the file name itself becomes corrupted, and not that the other server is just unable to properly display UTF-8 names?

Comment: After double checked, I found that just like you said. I didn't realize that because I am 100% sure that I have set `locale` correctly. But I forgot to install corresponding language pack... Thanks a lot.